# Constant symplectic structure

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, frechet-manifold

Let $E$ be a Frechet space and $\mathcal{F}$ be a non-degenerate bounded skew symmetric bilinear map $\mathcal{F}: E\times E\to \mathbb R$ on $E$.   We can identify $TE$ with $E\times E$, with this identification, $\mathcal{F}$ defines 2 form $\omega$ on $E$, by the following:
$$\omega_x: T_x E\times T_xE\to \mathbb R$$
$$\omega_x(v, w):= F(\tilde{v}, \tilde{w})$$
where $\tilde{v}$ and $\tilde{w}$ are identification of $v,w\in T_x E$ with $E$.

I feel this definition is well defined for Frechet manifold and also the form defined in this way is closed.  Is this true.

Comment: for the safe side, assume $E$ is a nuclear Frechet space where $TE\simeq E\times E$.

Comment: I'd like just to mention that in infinite dimensions there are (at least) two notions of a symplectic structure: a **weak** symplectic structure, when $\omega$ induces only an _injective_ map $TE \to T^{*}E$ and a **strong** symplectic structure when $\omega$ induces an _isomorphism_ $TE \to T^{*}E$. A non-degenerate bilinear map as above will give you only the weak version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. See Section 48 of

- [Peter W. Michor: Topics in Differential Geometry. Graduate Studies in Mathematics, Vol. 93 American Mathematical Society, Providence, 2008](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/dgbook.pdf)